# SQL Server 2008 Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have to get some data from a table who's name is defined at run time, so I'm using the method of first selecting the data into a global temp table and the to my actual temp table. But I'm getting Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
A don't get why it is trying to match the columns as its a select into statement. My code is:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempData') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #tempData
    if object_id('tempdb..##temptbl') is not null
    begin
        drop table ##temptbl
    end

    execute('select * INTO ##temptbl from Repo.dbo.'+@tableName)

    select * INTO #tempData from ##temptbl
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you definitely declaring that variable (@tablename)? I don't see it in your code here.

Comment: Yes I am, this is a part of a very big procedure, but I'm getting a run time exception here, in the execute bit

Comment: And does that piece of code run ok on it's own if run separately?

Comment: Yes If I remove this part and statically insert some records it runs fine

Comment: Can you script out enough of the code to reproduce the error you are getting?   We can't really help you if the error is because of some part of the code you aren't showing us.

Comment: Global temp tables a huge red flag that something is not thought out correctly. There are huge problems with concurrency and global temp tables. Is there some reason you don't know the definition of the table ahead of time? Or is this some sort of generic reporting tool so you only pass the table name and the report is generated for any table in the system?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've missed the begin...end from your first IF statement. This is likely making the drop of the global temp table fail as it's still working out the first part;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempData') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tempData
END
GO
IF object_id('tempdb..##temptbl') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##temptbl
END

EXECUTE('select * INTO ##temptbl from Repo.dbo.'+@tableName)

SELECT * INTO #tempData FROM ##temptbl
```

Comment: `BEGIN..END` aren't needed if only one statement is dependent on the `IF` statement.

Comment: the 'DROP TABLE #tempData' wouldn't be dependent upon the IF above it?

Comment: Yes, but it's the only statement that is dependent on it.   If there is only one statement in the `BEGIN..END` block, then the `BEGIN..END` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
          simpe use this 





  declare @tableName nvarchar(50) = 'tblTest'

            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempData') IS NOT NULL
                    DROP TABLE #tempData

            IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##temptbl') IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                DROP TABLE ##temptbl
            END

            execute('select * INTO ##temptbl from dbo.'+ @tableName)

            select * from ##temptbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query might solve your issue :-

```
declare @tableName varchar(50) = 'Test'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempData') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tempData
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##temptbl') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##temptbl

execute('select * INTO ##temptbl from dbo.'+@tableName)

select * INTO #tempData from ##temptbl
```